# How to get N set of data base on one column

Tags: mysql

example, my data

```
XXX yyy  order_time
x1  y1  2019/11/11 00:11:22
x2  y2  2019/11/11_00:11:22
x3  y3  2019/11/11_00:22:33
x4  y4  2019/11/11_00:33:44
x5  y5  2019/11/11_00:33:44
x6  y6  2019/11/11_00:44:55
```

To get all data, I can use:

```
select xxx,yyy,order_time from my_table where condition=bala;
```

To get 3 set of the order_time

```
select distinct(order_time) from my_table order by order_time limit 3;
```

But how to combine them together?
I want to get all data that the order time within the 3 set of the order_time.

expect would be:

```
XXX yyy  order_time
x1  y1  2019/11/11 00:11:22
x2  y2  2019/11/11_00:11:22
x3  y3  2019/11/11_00:22:33
x4  y4  2019/11/11_00:33:44
x5  y5  2019/11/11_00:33:44
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your expected result as a table? And which mysql version are you using?

Comment: @danblack added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8+

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY order_time) dr
              FROM my_table
              WHERE <conditions> )
SELECT xxx,
       yyy,
       order_time
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 3
```

MySQL 5.+

```
SELECT my_table.*
FROM my_table 
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT order_time 
       FROM my_table 
       WHERE <conditions>
       ORDER BY order_time 
       LIMIT 3 ) times USING (order_time)
/* WHERE <conditions> */
```